# How can I display the time stamp of a file with seconds, from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I display the time stamp of a file with seconds,

(creation date/time, modified date/time, and access date/time.  All, with seconds).

from the command line?

Comment: @boboes if you thought this one was interesting, you should check out this one! http://superuser.com/questions/973547/how-can-i-display-all-8-ntfs-timestamps

Comment: on a different note, the question here may be relevant to the problem and answer here  http://superuser.com/questions/588608/why-does-robocopy-say-this-file-is-older   in that perhaps in certain cases according to the answer there, robocopy might take seconds into account, in which case, this question that shows seconds, is particularly relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use PowerShell to get that information.

1. Start PowerShell from the startmenu
2. Use:

`Get-ChildItem <<File or Folder>> -Force | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Mode, Length`

It will print out the information for you. `-Force` is used to get items that cannot otherwise be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files. Additionally you can use the `-Recurse` option to recurse into folders.

---------  //added by barlop

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem c:\q\az.png -Force | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime
, Mode, Length


FullName       : C:\q\az.png
CreationTime   : Sun 28 Apr 2013 12:12:59
LastAccessTime : Sun 28 Apr 2013 12:12:59
LastWriteTime  : Tue 22 Jul 2008 05:01:47
Mode           : -a---
Length         : 79248

PS C:\Users\user>
```

-------------- // end added by barlop

An easy way to recurse into folders and have a file that can be imported into Excel is to use:

`Get-ChildItem C:\ProjectX -Force -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Mode, Length | Export-Csv c:\temp\ProjectX_files.csv`

//pic added by barlop
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
E:\blah>cscript //nologo filetimes.vbs a.a
Times for file: E:\blah\a.a
Created:  15/12/2014 2:04:22 AM
Modified: 31/05/2016 10:42:31 PM
Accessed: 15/12/2014 2:04:22 AM
```

contrast with

```
E:\blah>dir a.a
31/05/2016  10:42 PM            26,990 a.a
```

(dir only shows one time at a time, e.g. /tw by default, or /tc or /ta  can write /t:w e.t.c.  see dir /? for other info)

So that vbscript file shows 3 times and seconds and in one command.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0  Then
   WScript.Quit
End If

strfileFolder = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments(0)) 

'this line only works with cscript

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Times for file: " & strfileFolder

Set v = objFSO.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0))
dm=v.DateLastModified
dc=v.DateCreated
da=v.DateLastAccessed
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Created:  "&dc)
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Modified: "&dm)
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Accessed: "&da)
```