# Windows Batch file to copy latest files to a new folder

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I want to copy the latest file from a Folder and its subfolders to a new location.

The following code works well, BUT I do not want to filter by Date AND Time (/O:D), but DATE only, so that all latest files from the same date will be copied to the new location as the latest files.

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "D:\Backups\DB\*.bak" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
copy "%NewestFile%" "D:\Backups\DB\Latest"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The following batch script makes use of the `forfiles` command, which is not available by default in Windows XP. If that's the operating system you use, you'll have to [manually download it](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/ResKit/y2kfix/x86/). While the syntax is similar, [it's not identical](https://superuser.com/questions/699769/batch-file-last-modification-time-with-seconds#701594).

```
@echo off

REM set the working directory
pushd "D:\Backups\DB"

REM get the latest modified .bak file
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir *.bak /b /o:-d /s 2^>nul') do (

REM copy the newest files
call :copyNewest %%G "Latest"

REM restore the previous working directory
popd
goto:EOF
)

:copyNewest
setlocal

REM make sure there's something to copy
if "%~1" == "" exit /b

REM check output folder
if "%~2" == "" exit /b

REM get the file path
set filePath=%~dp1

REM strip the trailing backslash char
set filePath=%filePath:~0,-1%

REM copy latest files which share the same date
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('"forfiles /p "%filePath%" /m "%~nx1" /c "cmd /c echo @fdate""') do (
forfiles /p "%cd%" /m *.bak /s /c "cmd /c echo @relpath | findstr /i /c:"\%~2" >nul || copy @path "%cd%\%~2" >nul" /d %%G
)
endlocal & exit /b
```